# monkeypatch function in module whose namespace was overwritten

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, biopython, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkeypatch a function in an external module I use, but monkeypatch can't seem to access the function because the namespace of the module gets overwritten on import.

Concretely, I use a `Bio.PDB.PDBList.PDBList` object (`biopython` module) in my code, and I am trying to patch `_urlretrieve` in [`Bio.PDB.PDBList`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/PDBList.py) to prevent calls to the internet and instead get files from a local directory, without having to mock the instance methods of `PDBList` which would be substantially more work. But when I try the naïve:

```
m.setattr("Bio.PDB.PDBList._urlretrieve", mock_retrieve)
```

pytest complains:

```
AttributeError: 'type' object at Bio.PDB.PDBList has no attribute '_urlretrieve'
```

On further inspection of [`Bio.PDB`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/__init__.py), I can see that the module namespace `.PDBList` seems to be overwritten by the class `.PDBList.PDBList`:

```
# Download from the PDB
from .PDBList import PDBList
```

So that would explain why pytest sees `Bio.PDB.PDBList` as a `type` object with no attribute `_urlretrieve`. My question is, is there any way to get monkeypatch to patch this 'hidden' function?

---

Concrete example of usage of `PDBList` class:

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBList import PDBList

_pdblist = PDBList()

downloaded_file = _pdblist.retrieve_pdb_file('2O8B', pdir='./temp', file_format='pdb')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right - since the `PDBList` class has the same name as the module `Bio.PDB.PDBList`, after `import Bio.PDB.PDBList` you won't be able to access the module by its name (shadowing problem). However, you can still grab the imported module object from the loaded modules cache and monkeypatch that:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock
import Bio.PDB.PDBList

def test_spam(monkeypatch):
    assert isinstance(Bio.PDB.PDBList, type)
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(sys.modules['Bio.PDB.PDBList'], '_urlretrieve', Mock())
        ...
```

Comment: Shiny! That is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I should go digging around `sys` more.

Comment: Glad I could help!